# ld makes wrong call instruction

Tags: c, x86, ld, osdev

I'm trying to make a small kernel, so far i've gotten to protected mode with A20 enabled, GDT loaded and kernel loaded from disk. In C i've tried function calls, but for some reason ld makes a wrong call instruction.
Here is the C code:

```
asm(".code32");
int a(int *d);
int main() {
        int c = 0;
        c = a(&c);
        c = a(&c);
        c = a(&c);
        while(1);
}
int a(int *d) {
        int b = 1;
        b *= 5;
        b *= 7;
        b -= 6;
        b *= 9;
        *d = b;
        return b;
}
```

My makefile (reduced) is:

```
KERNEL-PARTFILE       = int/parts/detailed-boot.prt
KERNEL-OBJECTFILE     = int/detailed-boot.o
KERNEL-SOURCEFILE     = src/detailed-boot.c
GCC                   = ~/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc
LD                    = ~/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-ld
VM                    = qemu-system-x86_64
SYSFILE               = lizard.bin

kernel:
        $(GCC) -ffunction-sections -ffreestanding $(KERNEL-SOURCEFILE) -o $(KERNEL-OBJECTFILE) -nostdlib -Wall -Wextra -O0
        $(LD) -o $(KERNEL-PARTFILE) -Ttext 0x7e00 --oformat binary $(KERNEL-OBJECTFILE) -e main --script=LDfile -O 0 -Ttext-segment 0x7e00 --verbose
run:
        $(VM) $(SYSFILE)
debug:
        $(VM) $(SYSFILE) -gdb tcp:localhost:6000 -S
```

LDfile:

```
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS {
        . = 0x7e00;
        .text . : { *(.text) }
        .data . : { *(.data) }
        .bss  . : { *(.bss ) }
}
```

The issue is in the linking. Running `objdump` (cross compiled) on `int/detailed-boot.o` produces:

```
int/detailed-boot.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048054 <main>:
 8048054:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048058:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 804805b:   ff 71 fc                push   -0x4(%ecx)
 804805e:   55                      push   %ebp
 804805f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048061:   51                      push   %ecx
 8048062:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
 8048065:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
 804806c:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 804806f:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048072:   50                      push   %eax
 8048073:   e8 2d 00 00 00          call   80480a5 <a>
 8048078:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804807b:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 804807e:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8048081:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048084:   50                      push   %eax
 8048085:   e8 1b 00 00 00          call   80480a5 <a>
 804808a:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804808d:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048090:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8048093:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048096:   50                      push   %eax
 8048097:   e8 09 00 00 00          call   80480a5 <a>
 804809c:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804809f:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 80480a2:   90                      nop
 80480a3:   eb fd                   jmp    80480a2 <main+0x4e>

080480a5 <a>:
 80480a5:   55                      push   %ebp
 80480a6:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80480a8:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 80480ab:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
 80480b2:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
 80480b5:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 80480b7:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
 80480ba:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 80480bc:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
 80480bf:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
 80480c2:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 80480c4:   c1 e0 03                shl    $0x3,%eax
 80480c7:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
 80480c9:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
 80480cc:   83 6d fc 06             subl   $0x6,-0x4(%ebp)
 80480d0:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
 80480d3:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 80480d5:   c1 e0 03                shl    $0x3,%eax
 80480d8:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 80480da:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
 80480dd:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 80480e0:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
 80480e3:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
 80480e5:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
 80480e8:   c9                      leave  
 80480e9:   c3                      ret
```

Nothing unusual. Running `ndisasm` on `int/parts/detailed-boot.prt` produces:

```
00000000  8D4C24            lea cx,[si+0x24]
00000003  0483              add al,0x83
00000005  E4F0              in al,0xf0
00000007  FF71FC            push word [bx+di-0x4]
0000000A  55                push bp
0000000B  89E5              mov bp,sp
0000000D  51                push cx
0000000E  83EC14            sub sp,byte +0x14
00000011  C745F40000        mov word [di-0xc],0x0
00000016  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000018  83EC0C            sub sp,byte +0xc
0000001B  8D45F4            lea ax,[di-0xc]
0000001E  50                push ax
0000001F  E82D00            call 0x4f
00000022  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000024  83C410            add sp,byte +0x10
00000027  8945F4            mov [di-0xc],ax
0000002A  83EC0C            sub sp,byte +0xc
0000002D  8D45F4            lea ax,[di-0xc]
00000030  50                push ax
00000031  E81B00            call 0x4f
00000034  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000036  83C410            add sp,byte +0x10
00000039  8945F4            mov [di-0xc],ax
0000003C  83EC0C            sub sp,byte +0xc
0000003F  8D45F4            lea ax,[di-0xc]
00000042  50                push ax
00000043  E80900            call 0x4f
00000046  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000048  83C410            add sp,byte +0x10
0000004B  8945F4            mov [di-0xc],ax
0000004E  90                nop
0000004F  EBFD              jmp short 0x4e
00000051  55                push bp
00000052  89E5              mov bp,sp
00000054  83EC10            sub sp,byte +0x10
00000057  C745FC0100        mov word [di-0x4],0x1
0000005C  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005E  8B55FC            mov dx,[di-0x4]
00000061  89D0              mov ax,dx
00000063  C1E002            shl ax,byte 0x2
00000066  01D0              add ax,dx
00000068  8945FC            mov [di-0x4],ax
0000006B  8B55FC            mov dx,[di-0x4]
0000006E  89D0              mov ax,dx
00000070  C1E003            shl ax,byte 0x3
00000073  29D0              sub ax,dx
00000075  8945FC            mov [di-0x4],ax
00000078  836DFC06          sub word [di-0x4],byte +0x6
0000007C  8B55FC            mov dx,[di-0x4]
0000007F  89D0              mov ax,dx
00000081  C1E003            shl ax,byte 0x3
00000084  01D0              add ax,dx
00000086  8945FC            mov [di-0x4],ax
00000089  8B4508            mov ax,[di+0x8]
0000008C  8B55FC            mov dx,[di-0x4]
0000008F  8910              mov [bx+si],dx
00000091  8B45FC            mov ax,[di-0x4]
00000094  C9                leave
00000095  C3                ret
```

Note the following:

```
0000001F  E82D00            call 0x4f
00000031  E81B00            call 0x4f
00000043  E80900            call 0x4f
0000004E  90                nop
0000004F  EBFD              jmp short 0x4e
```

The call instructions go to `4F`, the infinite loop! They should go to `51`, the function .
I followed the osdev.org cross compiler tutorial (https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler), using `i686-elf` and `~/opt/cross`.
If you need more info, I have a github repository public (https://github.com/saltq144/lizard)

Edit:

Running `ndisasm -b 32` shows correct results. I'll finish my GDT and see what happens.

Edit 2:

After finishing my GDT, i tried `make debug`. QEMU still jumps to 4F, not 51.

Comment: First of all the 2 disassemblers are using different bitness. The first one use 32bits instructions decoding, considering the call opcode 5 bytes long (4 bytes of relative offset). The second decodes opcode `E8` as 16bits relative call (offset 2 bytes long). This leads to an extra instruction added `add [bx+si],al` (a known IA32 pseudo `nop` instruction which opcode is `0x0000`). Because a relative call add the signed offset to the start memory of next instruction to achieve subroutine address in case of 16 bits offset the sub address is computed 2 bytes before @ the jump address.

Comment: When the offset is considered 32bits the computed address will be the correct one at subroutine address.

Comment: At this point you have to check 2 things. One is if you correctly instructed the assembler about the processor mode (real or protected, 16 or 32 bits). Then if you have specified to `ndisasm` to consider protected mode code (32bits) because it seems to be disassembling 16bits code. Considering that `objdump` is using the ELF file, it should be correct and your code is compiled for 32bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem, I used bad options with ndisasm.